# Table of Contents Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-2010

So I am trying to create a web part in SharePoint 2010 that displays the 5 most recent subsites created.

I've come to find that the Table of Content Web Part has this functionality(through limiting the number of viewable items), but it is also showing the Sites, Lists, Libraries and Discussions links.

Updating the Navigation settings only changes the number of subsites listed, and changing the web.config file does not remove these links either.

I saw a solution using a Library and javascript, but I would prefer to keep my solution limited to out of the box features (or, at most editing the web.config file).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this source, http://blog.insource.com/applicationdevelopment/sharepoint/listing-sub-sites-with-the-table-of-contents-web-part.html

Comment: Unfortunately that link is now dead.

Comment: That's unfortunate, the best alternative I could find was this thread: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3884/webpart-to-display-list-of-subsites

Comment: @Dark An alternative I have created is a custom workflow action that creates a subsite after entering a list item. Then you can maintain a list of your subsites in the list and just use a list view webpart to display them.